# Have "Questions that may already have your answer" on other meta sites show results from MSE as well

Tags: feature-request, meta, asking-questions, per-site-meta

The following question appeared on meta.webmasters: [Accepted answer appearing below most voted answer](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/804/accepted-answer-appearing-below-most-voted-answer)

However, it's already covered multiple times here on Meta Stack Exchange e.g. 
[Vote ordering of accepted answers has changed: Accepted below top voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/vote-ordering-of-accepted-answers-has-changed-accepted-below-top-voted)

There's already a question about doing this for non-meta sites here: [Show "Questions with similar titles" from other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123022/show-questions-with-similar-titles-from-other-sites)

I realize that it may not be worth the resources required.

Would it be worthwhile to add a note to the question entry area on other meta sites? It could suggest that meta.stackoverflow be checked for questions regarding site functionality, feature requests and bug reports.

Comment: I was just going to ask a similar question! It probably happens everywhere but I was triggered by [this question at movies](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/534/what-do-with-an-obviously-wrong-answer-marked-as-correct). We could at least tell people on other meta sites that meta.stackoverflow is the "mother" meta (in the faq, or when starting a new question).

Comment: Related (not the same): [Can there be a link to meta.stackoverflow in all the other meta sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87018/can-there-be-a-link-to-meta-stackoverflow-in-all-the-other-meta-sites).

Comment: Funny thing, I just added an answer to a question related to the movies question you mentioned: [Should Discussion Questions have an Accepted Answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135928/166045)