# Improve "questions that may already have your answer" suggestions

Tags: bug, duplicate-suggestions

I just posted a question titled "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258829/questions-that-may-already-have-your-answer-check-on-local-meta-and-metase".

Shadow Wizard found that it was a duplicate of [Have "Questions that may already have your answer" on other meta sites show results from MSE as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136863/have-questions-that-may-already-have-your-answer-on-other-meta-sites-show-resu) and of course I agreed and accepted the suggestion to close it.

The question that mine was a duplicate of, never showed up in the "Questions that may already have your answer" list. Although there are **six** matching words in the same order in both titles (seven if you if you match case insensitive). Can the question matching be improved so that a few (four?) or more exact same, non-trivial, words, matching in the title actually shows such a question title (at the top of the suggestion list)?

Comment: Yeah, cause I keep getting marked as dupes because I can't find a question that already has my answer.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know if they're adjusting this at the moment on StackOverflow, but now I get no suggestions mentioning MemberwiseClone when I try something like "Changing MemberwiseClone to a constructor". Seeing as I saw there were MemberwiseClone suggestions as typed, I eventually used "MemberwiseClone: Changing to a constructor" to at least get some questions to check. I didn't confirm seeing the same issue when trying to ask a question related to this here, so I'm guessing it's either SO-specific or "constructor" is just very common in SO.